# Unable to install Mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, mapbox

I am trying to install Mapbox iOS SDK using CocoaPod. I have already created the .netrc in the Home directory as suggested:

```
machine api.mapbox.com 
login <my login account>
password <my secret key>
```

Below are my Pod file

```
use_frameworks!
target 'MyApp' do

pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 6.2.1'
end
```

Below are messages after running 'Pod Update' and 'Pod Install'

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK 6.2.2 (was 6.2.0)

[!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/54/rt4ptnd94_j8x3s3_nxn1gfc0000gn/T/d20201108-21218-qopblk/file.zip https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.2.2/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.10.0 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue you have to add .netrc in root directory of your Mac not of the project

And follow this example:

machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password your_password

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the Downloads:Read permission for your secret token.

[Configure credentials](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/#configure-credentials)

> From the token creation page, give your token a name and make sure the
> box next to the Downloads:Read scope is checked.

Comment: The secret token has already got "Download:Read" scope checked but still not working

Comment: I am in the same boat. @MichaelAnderson were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution for this?@MichaelAnderson

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring due to the improper configuration of public and private key.
you have to do exactly as mentioned in the official documentation (for keys configuration only , if using Flutter )-
https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/

You can refer to this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFDx6tLipmw&t=441s

Comment: Pleas report the key passages of the cited documentation also here, only link answers are not accepted